# MongoDB: two $or's combined with an implicit AND - expected behaviour?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In the MongoDB documentation is says that

```
db.inventory.find( {
  $and : [
      { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
      { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
  ]
})
```

> This query cannot be constructed using an implicit AND operation, because it uses the $or operator more than once.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

What should you expect if you do use implicit AND for two OR's? Is the behaviour well defined?

From this experiment, it looks like it ignores the first OR predicate..

```
> db.mytest.insertMany([
{w: 0,  x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
{w: 0,  x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 },
{w: 0,  x: 0, y: 1, z: 1 },
{w: 0,  x: 1, y: 0, z: 0 },
{w: 0,  x: 1, y: 0, z: 1 },
{w: 0,  x: 1, y: 1, z: 0 },
{w: 0,  x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 },
{w: 1,  x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
{w: 1,  x: 0, y: 1, z: 0 },
{w: 1,  x: 0, y: 1, z: 1 },
{w: 1,  x: 1, y: 0, z: 0 },
{w: 1,  x: 1, y: 0, z: 1 },
{w: 1,  x: 1, y: 1, z: 0 },
{w: 1,  x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 },
])
...
>db.mytest.find({$or: [ {w: 1}, { x: 1} ],$or: [ {y: 1}, { z: 1} ]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e64d"), "w" : 0, "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "z" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e64e"), "w" : 0, "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "z" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e650"), "w" : 0, "x" : 1, "y" : 0, "z" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e651"), "w" : 0, "x" : 1, "y" : 1, "z" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e652"), "w" : 0, "x" : 1, "y" : 1, "z" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e654"), "w" : 1, "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "z" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e655"), "w" : 1, "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "z" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e657"), "w" : 1, "x" : 1, "y" : 0, "z" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e658"), "w" : 1, "x" : 1, "y" : 1, "z" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ce696828f7ac6a3372e659"), "w" : 1, "x" : 1, "y" : 1, "z" : 1 }
>
```

I'm asking the question because the behaviour seems to me to be inconsistent. I mistakingly used an implicit AND with OR's in a couple of places in my code. One of them appeared to give the same answer as you would expect from using and explicit AND. It was a complex query, so I may have made a mistake either in the query or in the testing. It would be good to know what's going on here ... there's possibly another bug that I'm still to weed out.

Comment: That is plane JavaScript not related to Mongodb .An object can not have properties with same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB treats

```
{$or: [ {w: 1}, { x: 1} ],$or: [ {y: 1}, { z: 1} ]}
```

as

```
{$or: [ {y: 1}, { z: 1} ]}
```

When 2 keys are the same in a MongoDB Query, the latest one replaces the earlier one.

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator), you will need a explicit `$and` here.